# Formtastic's datetime select with user-specific timezone

Tags: formtastic

We've got a MongoDB collection of events records with a scheduled_at datetime field that is saved in UTC. Each user has a specific time zone that we apply to timestamps on the front-end.

I can't figure out how to get formtastic's date time select to respect the user's timezone when *editing* a given event record. The code snippet looks like this:

```
f.input :scheduled_at, :as => :datetime, :input_html => { :value => event.scheduled_at.in_time_zone(Time.zone) }
```

It doesn't look as if I can override the value of the field that way; the scheduled_at drop downs still just shows UTC, instead of the proper Time.zone. Does anyone know what the correct approach for this is?

Comment: Did you ever determine a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed a `DateSelectInput` to show the time in UTC (long story, for legacy support). The only way to do this is to create a input that inherits from `DateTimeSelectInput` in your case (`DateSelectInput` in mine). This is because `Timeish`gets the value directly from the form object: https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/blob/3.1.3/lib/formtastic/inputs/base/timeish.rb#L159 (at least on the latest version)

This is the code for mine, but you get the gist, simply alter the value and present itself as the parent class so all the CSS and else, work as intended.

```
class UtcDateSelectInput < Formtastic::Inputs::DateSelectInput
  def value
     super.utc if super.respond_to? :utc
   end

  def as
    'date_select'
  end
end
```